# javascript functions in objects

Tags: javascript, function

I was trying to "put a function into an object" so I wanted to do something like this but I'm getting errors everywhere.

```
var someobject = {
    makename(1)  : null,
    makename(2)  : null,
    makename(3)  : null,
    makename(4)  : null
};

function makename(num) {
    return (identifier + ' Bot' + num)
}
```

Comment: yeah, json keys cannot be the result of a function call

Comment: actually, I think in es6 there are computed keys or something of that sort

Comment: They can if you use bracket notation instead, that's the only way to get dynamic keys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern (ES2015) JavaScript environments, you can do this:

```
var someobject = {
  [makename(1)]: "foo",
  [makename(2)]: "bar"
};
```

The `[ ]` wrapper around the property name allows it to be an arbitrary expression. The result of evaluating the expression is interpreted as a string and used as the property name.

Comment: :-), thats what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

```
var someobject = {}

someObject[makename(1)] = null;
someObject[makename(2)] = null;
someObject[makename(3)] = null;
someObject[makename(4)] = null;
```

This works everywhere. However, @pointy's solution is nicer!